# Integral of 1/sinx between 0 and 1 diverges.

Tags: improper-integrals

I am learning about ways to test if an integral converges or diverges and I am stuck with this one:
$\displaystyle{\int{{\rm d}x \over \sin\left(\, x\right)}}$ between $0$ and $1$.

The tests I know are:

1. The *Direct Comparison Test*.
2. The *2 Way Limit Comparison Test*.
3. The *1 way Limit Comparison Test*.

   and *The Dirichlet Test*.

Am I right in thinking that this integral diverges ?. And is there a way to prove it using those tests ?. Thank you !.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Try to do a comparison with $\int_0^1 \frac 1x$.

Comment: $\sin(x)$ ~ $x$ when $x$ is small. So since $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}$ diverges, you can say the same about the $\sin$ one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A comparison works:

For $0 < x \leq 1$, $0 < \sin x < x$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sin x} > \frac{1}{x}$. Thus

$$\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{\sin x} dx \ \ > \ \ \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{x} dx$$

The second integral diverges to $\infty$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$ and hence so does the first.

Comment: Importantly, the last integral diverges to $+\infty$. The comparison would not have been useful if it diverged by oscillation, or to "the wrong infinity". This is probably clear, but still warrants stating for formality.

Comment: @Ian, good point yet indeed it is clear as everything's positive here.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Simon S has already answered this question, but it's nice to not have to find any inequalities. The limit comparison test will apply since $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ are positive on the interval $(0,1]$. We can also tell by the integrand that the problem occurs at $x=0$ so we will consider the following

$$ \lim_{a \to 0} \int_a^1 \frac{1}{\sin x} dx  $$

We know that

$$\frac{1}{x} \sim \frac{1}{\sin x} \mbox{as } x \rightarrow 0  $$

and that

$$ \lim_{a \to 0} \int_a^1 \frac{1}{x} dx  = \lim_{a \to 0} [\log x]_a^1  $$

$$ = \lim_{a \to 0} [\log 1 - \log a]  $$

So we would conclude that the limit diverges to $+\infty$, meaning the second improper integral does not exist. Thus, by the limit comparison test

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sin x} dx  \mbox{ does not exist}$$